# Extend Dexterity add form without extending the type

Tags: forms, plone, dexterity

For a custom Dexterity type, I'd like to add a checkbox to the (autogenerated) add form, asking user whether to also create some associated subcontent.

Upon form submit, a customized factory would then create content if needed, remove the custom field and have the default dexterity factory do the rest. The custom field value is not to be stored.

I've assumed the form could be extended by overriding `additionalSchemata`. Here's the schema extension:

```
from zope import schema
from zone.interface import alsoProvides
from plone.supermodel import model
from plone.autoform.interfaces import IFormFieldProvider 

class SchemaExtension(model.Schema):

   createcontent = schema.Bool(
      title=u'Create default content',
      default=True,
      required=False
   )

alsoProvides(SchemaExtension, IFormFieldProvider)
```

And the form:

```
class ExtendedAddForm(add.DefaultAddForm):
   portal_type = 'customdexteritytype' 
   additionalSchemata = (SchemaExtension,)
```

However, for some reason with this, only string 'None' and the custom field is shown on the add form, so something is wrong. Furthermore, upon submit, an errror is thrown:

```
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <Acquisition.ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper object at 0x83e48c0>, <SchemaClass SchemaExtension>)
```

How can the form be extended? Preferably without grok in the picture.

Comment: What about manually add the checkbox to the template by customize some parts (or one part) of the template? This question shows you how to manipulate the template http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315829

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing a custom add form?

Comment: That's what I meant too :-)

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there could be a generic solution that could be applied as-is to any dexterity content type.

Comment: Come to think of it, the template would indeed seem to be generic... I'll try that.

Comment: Note: If the option is not stored, a custom add form would also be needed, since the object creation event handler never gets the form data, (and neither does a custom factory, fwiw).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that you may find somewhat easier. Declare your schema as usual, then specify that your `createcontent` field be shown on the add form and omitted on the edit form.

```
from plone.autoform import directives as form
from z3c.form.interfaces import IAddForm

class ISampleSchema(model.Schema):
...
    createcontent = schema.Bool(
        title=u'Create default content',
        default=True,
        required=False
    )
    form.omitted('createcontent')
    form.no_omit(IAddForm, 'createcontent')
...
```

(This is possible, maybe even a bit easier for schema defined via XML. See 
http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/reference/dexterity-xml.html#omitted )

This will leave `createcontent` stored on your object instances, but do you really care?

Now, create a handler for `zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent` to do whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Steve, good thinking - indeed the point of not storing the field was really about not showing it to users afterwards in any way.

Answer (score 2):

+1 @SteveM's answer.

But I just got another idea, bit more generic so you could reuse it on other DX content without modifying the form.

1. You have to write a simple behavior.

   By default you can choose between attribute storage and annotation storage for your new behavior. [Checkout the docs](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/behaviors/schema-only-behaviors.html#using-annotations)

   Your behavior resgistration could look like this

```
<plone:behavior
    title="title"
    description="description"
    provides=".some.Interface"
    factory="plone.behavior.AnnotationStorage"
    marker=".marker.Interface"
    />
```

2. Instead of of using the Annotation storage.

   ```
       factory="plone.behavior.AnnotationStorage"
   ```

   You could write a NullStorage, which actually does not store anything.

   In the following code snipped I adapted the annotation [storage code](https://github.com/plone/plone.behavior/blob/73a673a475f060e635224de42ad30b9c053475ba/plone/behavior/annotation.py) of plone.behavior.

```python
class NullFactoryImpl(object):
    """Null storage for behaviors
    """

    def __init__(self, context, schema):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return None

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        pass

class NullStorage(object):
    """Behavior adapter factory class for storing nothing :-).
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, context):
        return NullFactoryImpl(context)
```

3. Now you can change the behavior factory to..

   ```
   factory="your.package.behavior.NullStorage"
   ```

I did not tested this solution, but it should/could work and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, +1 for preventing the field from being stored.